# generate 4 digit random number using substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute below code:

```
var a = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
a = a.substring(-2);
```

I am getting error like `undefined is not a function` at line 2, but when I try to do `alert(a)`, it has something. What is wrong here?

Comment: What does `alert(a)` have?

Comment: `Math.floor` returns a **number**. Numbers don't have a `substring` method.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

That's because `a` is a number, not a string. What you probably want to do is something like this:

```js
var val = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
console.log(val);
```

- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will generate a floating point number in the range [0, 1) (*this is **not** a typo*, it is standard mathematical notation to show that 1 is excluded from the range).
- Multiplying by 9000 results in a range of [0, 9000).
- Adding 1000 results in a range of [1000, 10000).
- Flooring chops off the decimal value to give you an integer. Note that it does not round.

---

**General Case**

If you want to generate an integer in the range [x, y), you can use the following code:

```
Math.floor(x + (y - x) * Math.random());
```

Comment: I can't regenerate a code that starts with a zero, such as `0123`.

Comment: @5ervant, that would be a 3 digit number. (Mathematically, the leading 0 does not matter.)

Comment: Beautify explanation to the answer @SumnerEvans

Answer (score 22):

This will generate 4-digit random number (0000-9999) using substring:

```
var seq = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 10000).toString().substring(1);
console.log(seq);
```

Answer (score 4):

I adapted Balajis to make it immutable and functional.

Because this doesn't use math you can use alphanumeric, emojis, very long pins etc

```
const getRandomPin = (chars, len)=>[...Array(len)].map(
   (i)=>chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length)]
).join('');


//use it like this
getRandomPin('0123456789',4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
    var a = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);   
    a = String(a);
    a = a.substring(0,4);
    alert( "valor:" +a );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: got to remember that when you do a math logic you problably will receive a data type as either int or double, therefore you got to convert the result to string to be handle by the substring function, hope this helps

Comment: How is this different from erkaner's solution? The `$(document).ready` call is unnecessary here.

Comment: Thats in case you use it in jquery code, but you are right otherwise is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

I've created this function where you can defined the size of the OTP(One Time Password):

```
generateOtp = function (size) {
    const zeros = '0'.repeat(size - 1);
    const x = parseFloat('1' + zeros);
    const y = parseFloat('9' + zeros);
    const confirmationCode = String(Math.floor(x + Math.random() * y));
 return confirmationCode;
}
```

How to use:

```
generateOtp(4)
generateOtp(5)
```

To avoid overflow, you can validate the size parameter to your case.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers don't have substring method. For example:

```js
let txt = "123456"; // Works, Cause that's a string.
let num = 123456; // Won't Work, Cause that's a number..

// let res = txt.substring(0, 3); // Works: 123
let res = num.substring(0, 3); // Throws Uncaught TypeError.

console.log(res); // Error
```

For Generating random 4 digit number, you can utilize `Math.random()`

For Example:

```js
let randNum = (1000 + Math.random() * 9000).toFixed(0);

console.log(randNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` is a number. To be able to use the `substring` function, it has to be a `string` first, try

```
var a = (Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)).toString();
a = a.substring(-2);
```

Comment: This generates a number with 6 digits rather than 4.

Comment: It also doesn't create a number but a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can get 4-digit this way `.substring(startIndex, length)`, which would be in your case `.substring(0, 4)`. To be able to use `.substring()` you will need to convert `a` to string by using `.toString()`. At the end, you can convert the resulting output into integer by using `parseInt`  :

```
 var a = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
 a = a.toString().substring(0, 4);

 a =  parseInt(a);

 alert(a);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v7dswkjf/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `a` is a number. You cannot apply `substring` to a number so you have to convert the number to a string and then apply the function.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/L0dba54m/

```
var a = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
a = a.toString();
a = a.substring(-2);
```

Comment: Your demo clearly shows that your solution produces a string of length 6.

Comment: yeah thats what i am trying to do

Comment: Well, the OP wants to create a 4 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) + 999);
  a = String(a);
  a = a.substring(0, 4);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// It Will Generate Random 5 digit Number & Char 
const char = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; //Random Generate Every Time From This Given Char
const length = 5;
let randomvalue = '';
for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);

    randomvalue += char.substring(value, value + 1).toUpperCase();

}

console.log(randomvalue);
```

Comment: it will generate random  value from char variable  with length 5 & in loop it will check the length and generate random 5 digit value from char variable and convert it to uppercase

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getPin() {
    let pin = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    let pinStr = pin + '';

    // make sure that number is 4 digit
    if (pinStr.length == 4) {
        return pinStr;
       } else {
        return getPin();
       }
    }

   let number = getPin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass Length of to number that need to be generated

```
  await this.randomInteger(4);
  async randomInteger(number) {

    let length = parseInt(number);
    let string:string = number.toString();
    let min = 1* parseInt( string.padEnd(length,"0") ) ;
    let max =   parseInt( string.padEnd(length,"9") );

    return Math.floor(
      Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min
    )
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is quite simple

```
const arr = ["one", "Two", "Three"]
const randomNum = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export const createOtp = (): number => {
      Number(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000).toString());
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.